# HTML content after (under) canvas element

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, position

I am using this code http://cssdeck.com/labs/pa0yqlki that displays a canvas covering the size of the browser's window.

I am able to display content on top of the canvas (by using absolute positioning and z-index: -1)

What I am not able to do is add content AFTER the canvas.
Once the canvas ends, and so does the window, I want to have an `<h1>` lets say. So a scroll bar should appear when the page is loaded I should be able to scroll a bit more so that I see the `<h1>`.

Any ideas?

Comment: `position:absolute` takes the canvas out of the document flow so the browser sees that you have nothing in the window and puts the h1 at the top-left of the window. You can use a large `margin-top` to push your h1 below the canvas so its both visible and so it causes scrollbars to appear.

Comment: Ok thank you for that. I will post my solution as a reply so other can see it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, thanks to [markE's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/411591/marke) reply I was able to achieve what I wanted.

```
[...] <canvas> </canvas>

<h1 id="myText"> Text </h1> [...]
```

this is the part of my HTML. The "myText" will be displayed under the canvas based on the size of the window.

To achieve that I added the following code in the CSS.

```
#myText
{
  padding-top: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with playing with CSS positions;

Try something like this:

```
<div>
  <canvas width="300" height="200" class="custom-canvas" />
  <div class="text">
    <div class="main">20 %</div>
    <div class="head">Completed</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.custom-canvas{
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
  width: 450px;
  height: 200px;
}
.custom-canvas {
  .text {
    bottom: 13px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 6px;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .head {
    margin-top: 14px;
  }
}
```

Play with left,right,top and bottom to achieve the exact position.